# How to properly prevent memcached "protocol injection"?

Tags: php, python, security, memcached, libmemcached

I found that when I put `\r\n` in the key to get the value from memcached server, it can be used to inject the memcached protocol to run another command. Following is the code example,

In PHP:

```
<?php
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('localhost', 11211);

$key = "foo\r\nset bar 0 10 10000\r\n";

echo $m->get($key);
echo $m->get($key); // <- hang here
?>
```

In Python:

```
import pylibmc

mc = pylibmc.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'])

key = 'foo\r\nset bar 0 10 10000\r\n';
print mc.get(key)
print mc.get(key) # <- hang here
```

If `key` is read from the user, a user could execute arbitrary commands in the memcached server, such as to run `flush_all` to slow down the website or set the password cache for another user.

Why the client library doesn't strip these illegal characters? How to properly prevent it in my code?

Comment: How about you don't let your users query for arbitrary keys?

Comment: Sometimes I need to use the slug as the key to get the content of the article. An attacker could put `%0D%0A` in the URL.

Comment: Well, then filter that. Or rather, only allow the user-given key to consist of characters which are definitely harmless.

Answer (score 2):

Encode the user value (base64 for example) and use the result as the key, or use the binary protocol.